# include separated exe application into VS Console project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reference, console

I have created console application on VS 2008, the console app use another exe file(using command line). I would like to add that exe file to my console application. Now I have one problem, if I build project I need to copy exe file manually to build folder.

Regards,
Tomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the .exe to your solution.
Then in the solution explorer : richt clik on the exe file and choose properties
In the properties:
**Copy to output folder : Copy if newer**