# How to use classes defined in a Visual Studio executable project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, dependencies, executable

Using Visual Studio 2008, I have a solution that contains two executable projects, A and B. Project B wants to use some classes from project A. I tried setting the dependency in B->Properties->Project Dependencies, but that didn't work. How do I do this? I have read that I should set B to contain a reference for B. I tried this and it did not work (I might be doing it wrong). Any help?

Comment: I would put the common code between the two executables in a library shared between the two projects. Then make the 2 projects dependent on that library. This will solve the linking of the library but you would need to take care of the include path.

Comment: that is an option, but not preferable.

Comment: If you do not want a common library you can include the common .cpp and .h files into both projects.

Comment: I am looking for another solution, one where I can simply say that B is dependent on A.

Comment: I think that to set up a dependency you need some kind of input from one project into the other. So using a library may be the only way.

Comment: I am not sure that this is true. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132150/how-to-add-exe-as-reference-in-my-web-application and http://stackoverflow.com/a/2466518/635125 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243054/include-separated-exe-application-into-vs-console-project

Comment: In my opinion none of those examples describe what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Are you using CLR / building a .NET application?

Comment: Any kind of executable, be it with a standard executable header (EXE) or shared library header (DLL), can be used as a shared library. Just export symbols from one EXE and import into another in the usual fashinon.

Answer (score 0):

in `B->Properties->Project Dependencies` You set that A will be compiled first. To set aviable A functions on B you need to set A as dll project and add in linker A.lib and set path for it in linkerAdditionalPath. I hope this will help you.
Next time to evade this issues I recomend you to use CMake for your projects.

Comment: That works for libraries not executables. The OP wants to use classes from 1 executable in a second executable without including the code or a libraray. This is possible with .NET / CLR but not unmanaged C++.